Ngrx Global SignalStore NullInjectorError
Getting NullInjectorError for signalStore that has {providedIn: root}!!
Why?
I am trying to inject my store into my component as a globalStore so added {providedIn: root} option for that store.
but it doesn't work until providing it locally by (providers: []) option of the component
